# Is $\min$ a non-expansive function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, lipschitz-functions, contraction-operator

I came across a note where it does something like the following:

\begin{align}
    l &= \min \{H, \max_{j\in [M]}\phi^\top(\theta + \xi^{j})  \} -  \delta \\
    & \geq [\max_{j\in [M]}\phi^\top(\theta + \xi^{j})  - \gamma ] -  [\delta - \gamma],
\end{align}

where $H \in \mathbb{N}$, $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\delta  \in \mathbb{R}$, $ \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. Also $\xi^j \in \mathbb{R}^d$ which are noise sampled from a normal distribution. 
As a reasoning for the inequality it just says, "$\min$ is a non-expansive function." I am not sure how the argument is working. It seems wrong to me. Can someone shed light regardless of the above being right or wrong?

Comment: Certainly the given context doesn't justify this step. We have instead $$l \le \max_{j \in |M|} \phi^\top(\theta + \xi^j) - \delta = \left(\max_{j \in |M|} \phi^\top(\theta + \xi^j) - \gamma\right) - (\delta - \gamma),$$since $\min\{a, b\} \le a$.

Comment: But why is $\min$ a non-expansive function and under what context steps similar to above is valid?

Comment: The step is valid if and only if you have$$\min\left\{H,\max_{j\in|M|}\phi^\top(\theta+\xi^j)\right\}=\max_{j\in|M|}\phi^\top(\theta+\xi^j)$$or equivalently$$\max_{j\in|M|}\phi^\top(\theta+\xi^j) \le H.$$Then the $\ge$ in the steps you provided would be an $=$. There's no way that $l$ is strictly greater than the RHS. I really don't know why they called $\min$ non-expansive, but this doesn't make sense without some kind of metric on doubleton sets, and even if there was one, the above steps are only true under the previous conditions.